# How is the scroll effect on the iphone 11 site built?

Tags: javascript, html, css

site - https://www.apple.com/iphone-11-pro/

I feel like I this is such a simple effect but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to achieve it. ( I am talking about the way elements are layered behind each other )

I figured it was some mix of `position:fixed/sticky` but I don't see how that is possible without a bunch of `height: ~100vh` etc and I hope that isnt how the effect is achieved on their site...

I don't even know what the proper name of this effect is to google it.

If anyone has any resources I could read up on or videos to watch, id greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @Syn, are you talking about the part where it talks about the rear cameras?

Comment: No not the cameras. Just scrolling through the site, the sections get revealed underneath other elements.

Comment: It's called parallax scrolling. At it's core, it's about having 2 or more elements behave differently on scroll, so they create cool looking effects, typically perspective. While it can be achieved via pure CSS it does have a few limitations (when pure). With JS there are fewer limits but it needs to be handled with care, as `onscroll` can fire very many times/sec on some devices, while other devices (typically iStuff) blocks JavaScript execution while the page is being scrolled, as they consider scroll smoothness way more important than whatever it is the user is trying to scroll through.

Comment: Check my answers, I provided many links & a simple approach than recreating the whole effect when other people actually did it.

Comment: So i am actually not a complete beginner. I am currently working as a front end dev so I know what parallax is etcetc. What I don't know how to do is the effect from the site. Elements stay fixed behind an element but once the element is scrolled past, the fixed element starts scrolling...

Comment: There is no one single effect on that page. There is a lot of parallax mixed in with several other effects. There won't be one technique to google there will be several, possible including some novel techniques. As is stands this is way to broad a question for stackOverflow.

Comment: @Syn I think keithclark is the same but don't forget it only demonstrates the idea, apple website doesn't demonstrate they are showing off, that's why it's different it's because a tutorial is meant to be simple, try utilizing that tutorial on a big website with many many items as they did, it will mostly be the same or at least very close

Comment: and AOS can create the same effect if you use it on big divs that take a lot of width, he demonstrated the idea using small divs, better try & see the result as this seems something that needs testing to work

Answer (score 0):

I would use `position: absolute` for both objects and declare their `z-index` order to show based on which layer is up-front.

I also see an `overflow:hidden` style a lot whenever you want to place an element's extra pixels away or behind other elements.

```css
#b1 {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display:table;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
}

#b2 {
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  display:table;
  position: absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div id="b1"></div>
<div id="b2"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

[AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) is a jquery library for on scroll animations

an example of usage

```
<div data-aos="fade-up"
     data-aos-duration="2000">
</div>
```

The site explains as your scroll.

some nice tutorials [keithclark](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/), [codepen](https://codepen.io/karldanninger/pen/NwzMzN) , [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

Comment: Consider adding this as a comment instead.  Ideally on Stack Overflow, some explanation of how it works or at least how to use it should accompany the answer.

Comment: Actually the site is the explaination, explains as your scroll

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately links break over time.  Stack Overflow is mean to be the main reference, and should have the content in your answer.

Comment: So ive used AOS on some other sites but this effect is completely different. The closest ive seen so far is from keithclark but not quite there. In the site I linked, elements look like they are positioned `fixed` but they suddenly become scrollable after an element finishes scrolling by. Hard to explain.

Comment: @Syn I added some tutorials anyway he can look for what he wants there, I tried them

Comment: @Brad I edited the question even before you reply 2nd time